# How do I compile with C++98 on MacOS?

Tags: c++, macos, c++11, c++98

I need to use C++98 for university programs, however even when passing the -std=c++98 flag to clang++ or to g++ it still seems to compile with c++11 and does not give errors if I use c++11 features. Here is a simple example:

```cpp
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int i;
    string number = "12";
    i = stoi(number);
}
```

My makefile:

```
all:
    clang++ -std=c++98 -c *.cpp
    clang++ -o main *.o

clean:
    rm -f *.o main

run: clean all
    ./main
```

Then I run the command make from Terminal (I tried using clang++ instead of g++ but it yields the same result) and receive the following output:

```
➜  cppversion make
g++ -std=c++98 -c *.cpp
g++ -o main *.o
➜  cppversion make
clang++ -std=c++98 -c *.cpp
clang++ -o main *.o
➜  cppversion
```

I believe this code should not have compiled if the -std=c++98 flag was working. How do I force code to compile with c++98?

Here is the version of clang:

```
Apple clang version 12.0.5 (clang-1205.0.22.11)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin20.2.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin\
```

Here is the version of g++:

```
Configured with: --prefix=/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr --with-gxx-include-dir=/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX11.1.sdk/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
Apple clang version 12.0.5 (clang-1205.0.22.11)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin20.2.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin
```

I have also tried adding the flag -pedantic but it does not fix the problem.

Using the flag -stdlib=libc++ yields the following:

```
➜  cppversion make
clang++ -stdlib=libstdc++ -std=c++98 -c *.cpp
clang: warning: include path for libstdc++ headers not found; pass '-stdlib=libc++' on the command line to use the libc++ standard library instead [-Wstdlibcxx-not-found]
main.cpp:1:10: fatal error: 'string' file not found
#include <string>
         ^~~~~~~~
1 error generated.
make: *** [all] Error 1
```

If I change it  to just -stdlib=libc++ then it still compiles:

```
➜  cppversion make
clang++ -stdlib=libc++ -std=c++98 -c *.cpp
clang++ -o main *.o
➜  cppversion
```

I found an easy solution: Use homebrew to install gcc and use g++-11 to compile.

Comment: Fails (as expected) here - live - https://godbolt.org/z/r3od175Wh  what versions of clang and g++ are you using ?

Comment: You may use this website to generate make files https://solver.assistedcoding.eu/makefilegen

Comment: @RichardCritten I've added the versions for clang and g++

Answer (score 2):

Try using `-std=c++98 -pedantic`.

This should strictly enforce the specific standard.

Answer (score 0):

<sup>Disclaimer: This is partly guesswork since I don't have a Mac</sup>

From my understanding, `clang++` is the default compiler on Mac and I would therefore not be surprised if even `g++` uses LLVM:s `libc++` and headers by default. `std::stoi` is unconditionaly declared in the `libc++` headers.

If you instead use`g++`:s `libstdc++` toolchain, you will probably get the error you want:

```
clang++ -stdlib=libstdc++ -std=c++98 -o main main.cpp
```

Comment: I don't think MacOS includes -stdlib=libstdc++ anymore (I have added the error to the post). Is there a way to manually install it?

Comment: @Charn I'm sure there is, but I have no experience with MacOS. Perhaps it's available in homebrew or whatever the packaging manager for MacOS is called. Worst case, you can just download gcc and compile it.

Answer (score 0):

I found an easy solution: Use homebrew to install gcc and use g++-11 to compile.

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.